# Often Inadvertently enter one of ScrollView's sub-items when scrolling the ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

When I am scrolling a ScrollView, it's very often that it enters the item of the ScrollView by accident.
How can I solve this problem?
Is it because of the scroll gesture duration?
How can I more clearly identify between the tap-gesture and scroll-gesture?

---

Update: I finally found it is because I set the sub-item's gesture as "TouchDown" but not "TouchUpInside". So that's my reason.

Comment: Do you need to use scrollview subitems tap while scrolling of scroll view?

Comment: @Prasanna There is no need to let subitem tapable while scrolling. So do you have any idea?

Comment: Actually I did not get your requirement till yet.... Please explain more...

Comment: @Prasanna When dragging a scrollView, it will enter the sub-item by accident. like this: http://imgur.com/a/fbnyG

Answer (score 0):

You should use a UIScrollView property.....which will delay to respond its subitems....

```
scrollViewObj.delaysContentTouches = YES;
```

This will respond its sub-items after the scroll of your scrollview finishes.

Comment: According to its definition, it is "// default is YES. ".And I add the statement you posted, it seems no effect. I wonder is it possible for me to get the touch-gesture duration and judge what the gesture is.

Comment: I finally found it is because I set the sub-item's gesture as "TouchDown" but not "TouchUpInside". So that's my reason.Thank you for your patient reply.